# How to change the order of CSS files. Load module's CSS before theme's CSS in magento2?

Tags: magento2, xml, head

I want to load all extension's css before custom theme css in `<head>` tag.
Right now extension's css file are loading after `styles-m.css` and `styles-l.css`
so I can not override the **extension css** from my **custom theme css**.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways:

1> All css load depending on order in `app/etc/config.php`. You can move your module before Magento_theme module then it will load all css of your custom module before your theme css. But in this case when you run setup:upgrade command then again your order will change.

2> You can create your custom module but the first latter of your namespace must be after `M` latter because order of module in config.php by default sort by alphabatically. Here you can write your custom css for override all css.

Answer (score 0):

For Module-specific styles, Retrive the directory : /_/web/css 
Then Modify /source/_theme.less: overrides the default Magento UI library variables values.

Include css:

Your custom default_head_blocks.xml should be located as follows: /Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml.
To include a CSS file, add the /" media="print|"/> block in  section in a layout file.  is specified relative to the theme web directory (/web) For example, the following illustrates how

stylesheets are included in the default Blank theme:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
  <head>
      <css src="css/styles-m.css" />
      <css src="css/styles-l.css" media="screen and (min-width: 768px)"/>
      <css src="css/print.css" media="print" />
  </head>
</page>
```

For More understanding, see the below URL:

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css-themes.html